# While including QtNetwork I get a lot of errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I use VS2010 with built-in Qt. I am trying to implement client and server, UDP is used.
I took example from book Qt4 programming GUI C++.

Implementation is mainly based on Qt library `QtNetwork`, but when I include it I get a lot of errors unknown for me like:

```
Error 8 error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name ****\AssemblyInfo.cpp 3
Error 9 error C2871: 'Reflection' : a namespace with this name does not exist ****AssemblyInfo.cpp 3
```

I think that errors are results of that library `QtNetwork` wasn't included properly.
Could you please advice me how to solve this issue?!

I tried to solve it by my means, and undertake following actions:

1. In VS: Qt \ Qt project settings \ add Network library, then `qmake -project`, `qmake`, `nmake`
2. In .pro file added string `QT += network` , then `qmake -project`, `qmake`, `nmake`

Both of them failed to cope with stated issue.

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>
#include "QtNetwork"
#include <QtGui>

class QTimer;
class QUdpSocket;

 class NetworkManagerServer : public QWidget
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     NetworkManagerServer(QWidget *parent = 0);

 private slots:
     void sendDatagramm();
 private:
     QUdpSocket* m_udpSocket;
     QTimer* m_timer;
     int m_messageNo;
 };

#include "NetworkManagerServer.h"

 NetworkManagerServer::NetworkManagerServer(QWidget *parent)
     : QWidget(parent)
 {
     m_timer = new QTimer(this);
     m_timer->start(2 * 1000);
     m_udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
     m_messageNo = 1;

     connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(broadcastDatagram()));

 }

 void NetworkManagerServer::sendDatagramm(void)
 {
     QByteArray datagramm;
     QDataStream out (&datagramm, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
     //out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
     out << "Hellow Qt::Network!";
     m_udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagramm, QHostAddress::LocalHost,5824);
 }
```

Here is list of errors which I get:

```
Error   8   error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name    ***\AssemblyInfo.cpp    3
Error   9   error C2871: 'Reflection' : a namespace with this name does not exist   ***AssemblyInfo.cpp 3
Error   10  error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name    ***AssemblyInfo.cpp 4
Error   11  error C2871: 'CompilerServices' : a namespace with this name does not exist ***AssemblyInfo.cpp 4
Error   12  error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name    ***AssemblyInfo.cpp 5
Error   13  error C2871: 'InteropServices' : a namespace with this name does not exist  ***AssemblyInfo.cpp 5
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that was the problem!!! 1. I created unit tests, later removed them from project, but haven`t removed from folder as result lots of errors, which i presented here 2. I tried to include QtNetwork with < > , but it didn`t works 3. But when I qmake -project, qmake, nmake and in generated .pro file included string QT += network project has compiled successfully!!!